# stage orientation in flash

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I want to implement device rotation in my flash game running on AIR and Android. I use Starling, and when i rotate my device, Starling reinitializes the OpenGL device/context, this will destroy all textures and load them again after reinitialization, and time in which stage is rotated is too big, at least this is what i think it do.

The question is: how can i improve the time in which my stage is rotated ?

I think i can listen to StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING to prevent it from default behaviour, and rotate manually my game (rotate main sprite). But if i do this, and for example rotate my device from default orientation to left, then i can't rotate them back to default because the orientation state remains on default and event isn't dispatched. Can i somehow set the orientation state without actually orient the stage?

Comment: Would it be possible to simply listen the accelerometer events manually instead of relying on the orientation events?

Comment: Great idea, it works, but systebar remains static, and i don't know how to change its position accordingly to calculated orientation:(

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use:

```
Starling.handleLostContext = true
```

to handle lost Context?
This option should be enabled before you launch your Starling instance and it is the easiest way to automatically handle lost context.